# How does a <3000 rep user cast a close vote on their own question?

Tags: support, reputation, vote-to-close, privileges

A question on The Workplace - [Boss expects me to attend meetings I was never informed about?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139670/boss-expects-me-to-attend-meetings-i-was-never-informed-about) - was recently put on hold, but something looked funny in the close votes:

---

[image: OP casts a close vote]

---

The author has less than the [3,000 needed reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to cast close votes but still managed to cast a close vote on their own question.

I guess voting on your own question is possible - but I would expect it to be subject to the same 3,000 rep requirement as any other close vote.

This seems strange. Is it the way close voting is expected to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. You need only [250 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) for the "View close votes on own question" privilege, but it lets you *cast* close (and reopen) votes on your own question as well:

> This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions.

Yours is a different situation, but *any* user can (regardless of their reputation) close their own question as a duplicate; that vote will be attributed to Community ♦ though.